# Can't add text to input type="tel" inside an IFrame using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, input, web-scraping

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FSsi.png)

[I'm trying to write into "Security Code"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2vu0.png)

[EDIT HTML CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWSnq.png)

I tried to write this:

`CVXPATH = '//input[@type="tel"]'
 cv=driver.find_element_by_xpath(CVXPATH)
 cv.send_keys("000")`

But I have this error:

```
line 242, in check_response 
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

How can I solve this?

[Problem clicking the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgYFt.png)
I tried this method that works perfectly for other buttons (different class) on the same web page but not this specific button, I also tried using div class:

```
xpathoo = '//button[@class="ncss-brand pt2-sm pr5-sm pb2-sm pl5-sm ncss-btn-accent continueOrderReviewBtn mod-button-width ncss-brand\
            pt3-sm prl5-sm pb3-sm pt2-lg pb2-lg d-sm-b d-md-ib u-uppercase u-rounded fs14-sm"]'
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpathoo).click()
```

Comment: Have you tried clicking the box before sending "000"?

Comment: Yes, nothing change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is present inside an `iframe` you need to switch to `iframe` first in order to send values in input field..

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it`() and following `CSS selctor.`

Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `element_to_be_clickable`() and following `XPATH`

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'iframe.credit-card-iframe-cvv')))
cv=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//input[@id="cvNumber" and @type="tel"]')))
cv.send_keys("000")
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: I have this 
`line 80, in until
 raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
 selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

Comment: @dip check the element is inside any frame or not? The xpath should work for you until any iframe is there?

Comment: Or can you post page source of the element.it is sometimes difficult to give proper resolution based on screenshot.

Comment: @dip : Can you try Xpath2 option?

Comment: @dip the element was there inside an iframe you need to switch it first.try updated answer.let me know how it goes.

Comment: I don't know how to do that

Comment: @Dip : I have already updated the code.Copy that code and try at your end and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I edited the question with another issue, can you help me also with this new problem, please?

Comment: @Dip : The stackoverflow every questions answered is used for reserch and future reader.It would be great if you post a new question.